# Is it possible to create a calculated or aggregated column within a GraphQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-java

I am new to **GraphQL** as a solution for retrieving data. My team will be using **PostgreSQL** among other data stores. Before I go down the rabbit hole, I am wondering if it is at all possible to do the following in GraphQL :

1. *Return a new, **calculated** column*

   ```
   SELECT col_a, col_b, (col_a / col_b) AS ratio FROM table_1;
   ```
2. *Return an **aggregated** result*

   ```
   SELECT col_a, sum(col_b, col_c) FROM table_1 GROUP BY col_a;
   ```
3. *Return a calculated column or aggregated result based on a **joined** set of information*

   ```
   SELECT SUM(a.col_a, b.col_d) FROM table_1 AS a JOIN table_2 AS b ON a.col_a = b.col_a;
   SELECT (a.col_a / b.col_d) AS ratio FROM table_1 AS a JOIN table_2 AS b ON a.col_a = b.col_a;
   ```

I understand that GraphQL is meant to fetch ***exactly*** what you specify in a query, nothing more and nothing less. Something like `SELECT * FROM TABLE;` is not permissible since a wildcard is the antithesis of specificity. I am hoping that you can still specify that you want something done to the result that is returned, but it is unclear to me the best practice for handling these sorts of situations.

I have found these **StackOverflow** posts so far, but not many :

- [GraphQL : Dynamic Filtering Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51863657/graphql-querying-with-dynamic-filtering-criteria)
- [Return Aggregate Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321688/can-graphql-return-aggregate-counts)
- [Aggregate Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036221/support-of-aggregate-function-in-graphql)
- [Return Calculated Type Dependent on Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331391/graphql-return-calculated-type-dependent-on-argument)
- [Table Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945940/graphql-queries-with-tables-join)

Comment: Is this question related to graphql-java specifically or to graphql in general? And the short answer is yes: graphql is only a  language to query a graphql server. You can define queries/mutations that will operate on calculated or aggregated or joined set of datas.

Comment: At the moment, just graphql in general. We'll definitely be using graphql-java (spring boot backend) and potentially be checking out graphql-js if it can help. So from what you're saying, it can provide subsets w/ conditions (queries) and alterations to the data (mutations), but any sort of calculated or aggregated field needs to be done by the database itself?

Comment: Yes. A graphql server provides a graphql schema, that defines the object types and the queries it will answer to (and a few other things). When receiving a query, the query is parsed, validated, and executed by a resolver. The resolver is in charge of returning the expected data (querying the database, performing operation, probably going through a service layer to do so...). This means you are in control and in charge of returning the aggregated data set.